# Images as links in MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, echo

I want to store image links into a database and then echo them onto a page.... Is this possible and how do I do it? (echo the actuall images and not the image link)

As you can see my code echo's out: The $link, $description and $title. I want to add another element which echos **$imagelink.**

```
echo "
<div class=\"pagination\" style=\"display:inline\"><ul style=\"background-color:#\"><li><div   class=\"span3_search\"><h2><a href='$link'><b>$title</b></a></h2><br><img id=\"result_img\"   src=\"img/lvmo.png\" /><br />
$description<br />
<a href='$link'>$link<br /><br /></a><p></div></li></ul></div>
";
```

Comment: Yes it is possible. What have you tried already?

Comment: I think I have wrote my question slightly wrong. My goal is to store the links in the database to the images. And echo them as images on to a the page. I have echoed 1 img but that was not connected to the database just using the img src element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Short answer

Simply `echo` out the URL of the image in the `src` attribute and the image will be displayed.

```
<img id="result_img" src="<?php echo $imagelink; ?>" />
```

## Worked Solution:

Table Design:

```
images

| id | title      | link                  | imagelink    | description |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | Some Title | http://www.google.com | myimage1.png | Some text   |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2  | My Title   | http://www.yahoo.com  | myimage2.png | Some text   |
```

SQL Query

```
SELECT title, link, imagelink, description FROM images WHERE id = ?
```

PHP

```
<?php

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT title, link, imagelink, description FROM images WHERE ID = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $ID);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($title,$link,$imagelink,$description);
$stmt->fetch();

?>
<div class="pagination" style="display:inline">
  <ul style="background-color:#">
    <li><div   class="span3_search">
    <h2><a href='<?php echo $link; ?>'><b><?php echo $title; ?></b></a></h2>
    <br />
    <img id="result_img" src="<?php echo $link; ?>" />
    <br />
    <?php echo $description; ?>
    <br />
    <a href='<?php echo $link; ?>'><?php echo $link; ?><br /><br /></a>
    <p></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Storing links to images in a database is easy. The slightly harder part is uploading the images and he hardest part is ensuring that the uploaded file and the database record are in synch.  What you store is typically the file name you saved the image into.

Edit:
You can also store the image file in a blob in the database.  This would need a program that takes a database key and return a binary stream in a response with the correct mime type.  This is a lot more work and most databases are more expensive and slower than the file system.

Comment: Im guessing storing the links is the same as how I have stored $links in the database. My goal is to store the $imagelinks and display them as images on the page and not the link.

Comment: @AndrewJohn Images are always displayed as src links to either files or a program that builds a stream.