# Link PHP Image to Specific URL

Tags: php, image

I'm having an issue finding a means to accomplish something.

I have a PHP file that outputs an image by selecting a random one from the database (sort of like a random ad banner).

This allows a user to use the following on their website (separate from mine) to show a random image.

```
<img src='image.php' />
```

However, I also want it to link to a specific URL from the database that matches the image showing. This is where I'm at a road block and can't figure out how to accomplish this. I want it to link to a PHP file on my server (view.php?id=123) and then re-direct to the corresponding URL.

How can I make it redirect to whatever image is currently displayed on the users site. I don't want to use Javascript on the users site. I want the user to be able to use the following:

```
<a href='view.php?id=123'><img src='image.php' /></a>
```

EDIT: these links would be absolute links to my website and not relative to the users website.

Is there a way of doing this with sessions?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You'll need to setup a column with a URL inside it for each image you wish to display. Then, concatenate the rows in PHP.

Comment: Yes, I currently have IMAGES and URLS as columns in a mysql database. The problem is the link/image code is going on other websites and is not using PHP. I've got a means to display the image, I just can't figure out a way to tie that image to a specific URL

Comment: See this answer on Stack http://stackoverflow.com/a/15735614/ that will show you how it's done. You can further your research which I did by using these words used on Google "display images and links mysql". There were many results.

Comment: Sorry I don't think your understanding my question (my faulty explanation).

Comment: So, `image1=link1_from_DB` / `image2=link2_from_DB` / `image3=link3_from_DB` from same corresponding rows, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use sessions.

In the image.php file, just set the image id in session. i.e.

```
$_SESSION['image_id'] = 5;
```

Then, just link with a normal url:

```
<a href='view.php'><img src='image.php' /></a>
```

Now, at view.php file, just based upon id stored into session, you can redirect anywhere you want or, just use

```
header('Location: http://example.com/some/other/image.png');
```

at same page.

Answer (score 1):

I don't follow what this has to do with sessions... but the core of your question is easily done.

Just like any other HTTP resource, you can redirect.

```
header('Location: http://example.com/some/other/image.png');
```

The browser will follow this redirect and display the image at the target.

Comment: Sorry I don't think I was as clear as I could have been. The image itself is a PHP file that outputs as an image to be used in img src. However it can be any number of images, each of which corresponds to a link url (in a mysql database). I can't figure out a way to have the link (a href) change depending on what image is randomly displayed